# Resharper - delegate code formatting single line want multiple

Tags: resharper

In Resharper6.1 after a 'Reset All Settings'

Code is formatted after a Ctrl E C as:

```
Assert.Throws<Exception>(delegate { c.Add(ANY_POSITIVE, -1); });
```

but I'd like:

```
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(delegate
                                     {
                                         c.Add(ANY_POSITIVE, -1);
                                     });
```

settings are:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Consider switching from anonymous methods to lambda expressions.

Comment: thanks TrueWill - am actually trying out anon methods to see if I like them better :-)